# Capistrano: Problem with permissions on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I have a problem deploying a Rails app to my server. Performing a

```
cap deploy
```

I get lots of errors, stating that chmod is not able to change permissions of (and only of) git object files:

```
...
 ** [out :: ██████████████] chmod: changing permissions of `/srv/www/kunsthof/releases/20101113162736/.git/objects/04/779c6d894bbea4c26d6e035f71cd1ab124cc90': Operation not permitted
...
failed: "sh -c 'chmod -R g+w /srv/www/kunsthof/releases/20101113162736'" on ██████████████
```

The files are put there on the deploy itself, so it should be possible for the deploy user to change their permissions. Any suggestions on what could be the problem here?

Comment: So after that error come a lot of errors that chmod can't touch the object files? Could you go ahead and be overly careful, and post the owner/group/permissions of an object file as well as a file the chmod succeeds on?

Comment: Capistrano immediately rolls back the deploy, so that the deploy destination is empty afterwards. Is there a way to prevent Capistrano from automatically cleaning up after a failure?

Comment: After executing the commands Capistrano did, I see that the files chmod is complaining about are owned by the git user, while all others are owned by the deploy user.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Is the deploy user the one who cloned the repo, or is the repo staying there and just being pulled into? Why does it need everything to be group-writable, anyway? I don't use capistrano, so hard to give specific help - but somehow either you need to keep it from trying to chmod those files, or make it possible for it to do it.

Comment: what strategy do you use with capistrano, those files could be a copy of files checked out in separate directory (usually shared/cache... - not sure the exact name) - then those files in cache can have different rights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually on deploy if you are using cached-copy, your repo will be cloned to a shared directory and will be rsynced/copied to the current release directory. While coping, you should be excluding .git directory and other unnecessary directories like spec / test (which are not going to used in production) with the following variable:

```
set :copy_exclude, [".git", "spec"]
```

With this, you are not going to copy the .git directory and should not be facing the permission problem on doing chmod there after.

Comment: [tag:+Epic].  I wrote a post-deploy cleanup script just to handle this issue.  Sometimes the mind thinks faster than docs can be nav'd.